# What network is called high-capacity network? Why?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

In this paper [deep_image_prior](http://sites.skoltech.ru/app/data/uploads/sites/25/2017/11/deep_image_prior.pdf) :

> To demonstrate the power of this parametrization, we consider inverse
>   tasks such as denoising, super-resolution and inpainting. These can be
>   expressed as energy minimization problems of the type
>
> [image]
>
> where E(x; x0) is a task-dependent data term, x0 the
>   noisy/low-resolution/occluded image, and R(x) a regularizer. The
>   choice of data term E(x; x0) is dictated by the application and will
>   be discussed later. The choice of regularizer,  which usually captures
>   a generic prior on natural images, is more difficult and is the
>   subject of much research. As a simple example, R(x) may be the Total
>   Variation (TV) of the image, which encourages solutions to contain
>   uniform regions. In this work, we replace the regularizer R(x) with
>   the implicit prior captured by the neural network, as follows:
>
> [image]

Then I see :

> A parametrization with high noise impedance. One may wonder why a
>   **`high-capacity network fθ`** can be used as a prior at all.

Here, I wonder why they call fθ `high-capacity network` ? What is the definition? Google just lead me to many non-relevant pages.